# The user license doesn't allow the permission: SubscribeToLightningReports

Tags: profile, change-set

Currently i'm not able to deploy change set from and to sandboxes in the spring17 release with force.com profiles added. This is only due to the "export reports" option with is ticked on both side (both environment). Do anyone know how to prevent this from happening ?

```
error : The user license doesn't allow the permission: SubscribeToLightningReports
```

When I removed this option from the general User permission, the change set is well validated. But i can't go on each profiles which uses the salesforce platform licence to update manually this option after each change set installation. Is there a better way to do this , or another options that is causing the error, but which need to be added with this option?

Comment: I don't know if it your twitter post but it may help you: https://twitter.com/xn/status/821115782851534849

Comment: no it is not my post, but they said there that this they are working on this issue which arises from spring17.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue today. But different context..so upvoted

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156819/why-i-am-getting-this-errorfield-integrity-exception-subscribetolightningreport

Comment: This was supposed to have been fixed before Spring '17 was released to production, but the bug seems to have re-introduced on 2017-02-15 or 2017-02-16.  I'm still seeing it in sandboxes updated to Spring '17 on 2017-02-11 running Spring '17 Patch 9 on cs1, cs40, and cs60.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gJdQAI

Comment: Yes, the problem still exist between my Spring17 sandboxes.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue multiple times, here is one temporary solution i used, you need to set this permission to false for salesforce platform licenses to deploy change sets without errors. Please follow these steps

1st approach:

1. Go to each SF Platform profile -> Edit -> uncheck run reports, report builder, Lightning Experience User -> save.
2. Click on edit again -> check them back except 'Lightning Experience User'. 
   Do this in both the environments you using for deployment -> upload the change set -> deploy.
3. If this doesn't work go to 2nd approach.

2nd approach:

1. -> Go to workbench salesforce in google - login with your sandbox or production. If you have multiple instances, then login to that instance first and then go to workbench so it takes you to the current sandbox
2. select queries on top - click soql query from drop down
3. Object = Profile, Fields = Id, Name, PermissionSubscribeToLightningReports, UserLicenseId (you can select multiple fields by using ctrl)
4. filter by "PermissionSubscribeToLightningReports" equals "true"
5. Now, you can see the list of all profiles with this permission set to true
6. look for any one profile which has salesforce platform license from the list and copy its UserLicenseId
7. add another filter below the "PermissionSubscribeToLightningReports" (click on + in green) - filter by "UserLicenseId" equals "paste the userLicenseId here" - click on query
8. Now you need to update all these profiles, so open each profile on other tab - select update - cntrl F and search by 'PermissionSubscribeToLightningReports' - make this field to false - click update and it gets saved.
9. repeat same process to all the profiles in the list
10. do this in both the environments you using for deployment -> upload changeset -> deploy

Answer (score 3):

There is a known issue in Spring '17:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gJdQAI

Salesforce support can manually apply a fix to affected orgs if you open a case.

Answer (score 3):

As workaround you can add:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <name>SubscribeToLightningReports</name>
</userPermissions>
```

to profile file.

Comment: This results in `Unknown user permission: SubscribeToLightningReports`

Comment: This works for Some customer community profile not for all

Comment: @luka 3z i can't use your suggestion, because Im deploying using change set

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, yet silly workaround.  Lets say you want to add permissions to Profile1:

1. change the name of Profile1 to Profile2
2. clone Profile2 and call it Profile1
3. Deploy your changes to the org to Profile1
4. Re-assing the Profile2 users to Profile1
5. Delete Profile2
6. Profit

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround that worked for me. If you are using ANT, try removing "description" tag from Profile xml file.