# why i am getting this error(FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION,SubscribeToLightningReports) and how to resolve it?

Tags: apex

```
 insert (new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId='0PS60000000CiNKGA0',
AssigneeId='00560000001mlAwAAI'));
```

> Line: 11, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The user
>   license doesn't allow the permission: SubscribeToLightningReports: []

Comment: The permission set includes a permission not allowed for the user's license type. You'll have to change the user's license type, or remove the permission from that permission set. You'll want to review the user's license type to see which permissions are allowed.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox .. I went to system permission for the permission set and unchecked the run report. Then it works.